# Recursively Filter directory of .cap/.pcap Files With tshark

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, tshark

I am trying to apply a `Wireshark` filter to a directory of `.cap` files created by `tcpdump`. I have about a 1000 .cap files awaiting filtering (we are intentionally capturing without filters to ensure we have all the data we need in case our hypothesis doesn't pan out). I cannot find any references to folks using `tshark` to recursively read a file, apply the filter, write out a new `.cap` file, then move on to the next, rinse, repeat.

My set up:

`Tcpdump` is dumping traffic and rolling to a new file once the file reaches `1GB` (yes, huge for pcaps). Just for reference, this is the `tcpdump` command I'm using:

```
sudo tcpdump -q -i <INTERFACE> -w path/to/capfile.cap -C 1000 -Z root
```

I can use `tshark` to apply a filter to a given `.cap` file and have it output to a new `.cap` file no problem using the following command:

```
tshark -R <FILTER> -r in.cap0001 -w out.cap0001
```

Tshark main page states,

> "-r  ...It is possible to use named pipes or stdin (-)
>   here..."

but I am by no means an expert with named `pipes`, `stdin`, nor am I programmer.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: If my answer worked for you, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If it didn't, add a comment asking for clarification or corrections if needed (I guess you can only comment on your own question as per your current reputation, but no worries I will read it).

Comment: Thank you Nacho, much appreciated. The only thing I had to change was `grep '\.cap$'` to `grep '\.cap'`

Comment: You are welcome. That means the files do not end with exactly `.cap`, I'm guessing `.cap0001` through `.cap1000` then, if that the case then yes, removing the `$` should do it. Cheers!

Comment: Ah makes sense, because that is indeed the case! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this directly with some shell commands.

Try the following, go to the directory where you have your captures and execute the following command:

`ls | grep '\.cap$' | while read f; do (tshark -R <FILTER> -r $f -w mod_$f); done`

This will produce new **.cap** files with the desired filter applied. Needless to say, this command can be properly tweaked to fit your personal needs, but it is a nice starting point.

---

**Commands explanation:**

`ls`: List all files contained in the current directory.

`|`: Pipe, the standard output of left hand side command is used as standard input of the right hand side command.

`grep '\.cap$'`: Ensures you work only with files ending with **.cap** will be matched. As per your comment, note that if the files do not end exactly with **.cap** this filter should be changed to `grep '\.cap'` since `$` tells `grep` that the line ends with whatever precedes it (in this example the *".cap"* string).

`while read f`: Reads each line returned by the previous commands.

`do (<COMMAND>)`: For each line read, it `do`es the COMMAND, which in this case is your `tshark` command.

`done`: Part of the `while` command syntax.

---

**Example command execution:**

```
# ls
fake.cap2  non_cap_file.txt  out2.cap  out.cap

# ls | grep '\.cap$'
out2.cap
out.cap
```

The following is the only line that you actually need to execute, the others are here just to illustrate the folder contents before and after the command execution.

```
# ls | grep '\.cap$' | while read f; do (tshark -R <FILTER> -r $f -w mod_$f); done
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
```

On a side note, I got this root warning because I did this quick test using root user...

```
# ls
fake.cap2  mod_out2.cap  mod_out.cap  non_cap_file.txt  out2.cap  out.cap

# ls | grep '\.cap$'
mod_out2.cap
mod_out.cap
out2.cap
out.cap
```

As you can see it grabs every **.cap** file, applies the filter specified and writes a new **mod_*.cap** file.